# Chart.js canvas cuts off doughnut stroke

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, charts, chart.js

I am using Chart.js to create a doughnut chart, but have ran into an issue where the stroke on the doughnut is getting cut off by the canvas object. Padding/margins on the canvas haven't solved the issue for me. Any ideas what is going on?

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLpzn3y7/)

HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

JS

```
var data = [{
    value: 30,
    color: "#F7464A"
}, {
    value: 50,
    color: "#E2EAE9"
}, {
    value: 100,
    color: "#D4CCC5"
}, {
    value: 40,
    color: "#949FB1"
}, {
    value: 120,
    color: "#4D5360"
}];

var options = {
    animation: true,
    segmentStrokeWidth : 5
};

var c = $('#myChart');
var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Doughnut(data, options);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the item you are drawing is larger than 400 pixels, this is actually a [**bug in ChartJS**](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/564). The current Alpha of ChartJS 2.0.0 addresses and fixes this problem. The `segmentStrokeWidth` is not taken into account when drawing the chart on the canvas, that causes the it to be larger than the canvas.

A fix for this version would be to subtract the `outerRadius` of your graph by half the stroke width:

```
var strokeWidth = 5;

var options = {
    animation: true,
    segmentStrokeWidth : strokeWidth
};

...

myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Doughnut(data, options);
myNewChart.outerRadius -= (strokeWidth/2);
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLpzn3y7/1/)